# Deploying laravel app to shared hosting - serialized closure error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to deploy my laravel app to a cPanel Shared Hosting. Here is the app and system features:

- Laravel: 8
- PHP: 8.1

I've done these steps:

- Changed .env file as like that:

```
    APP_URL=http://example.com/
    APP_LOG_FILE=/home/example/example/storage/logs/laravel.log
        
    DB_DATABASE=dbname
    DB_USERNAME=user
    DB_PASSWORD='pass'
```

- I pointed out my url to `/home/example/example/public` folder.
- I've cleared all caches and regenerated app key on my local. And I uploaded the files.
- Removed `storage` folder in the `public` folder.
- Followed the steps suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53776826/284199).

When try to access, it throws this error:
[image]

I can't understand what's the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Showing us the index.php is not very helpful, because it's the same for every Laravel instance. What's inside ".unknown0"? Looks like unserialize is called in there.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't added the error message to show you the index.php. Also I haven't called unserialize.

Comment: Tried php artisan route:clear ?

Comment: Adding a screenshot of what happens in ".unknown0" would really help to get a better understanding for what causes the problem.

Comment: @justsomexanda-a6a2f5842 sorry, I misunderstood. It redirects me to `vendor/laravel/serializable-closure/src/Serializers/Signed.php` and highlights the `throw new InvalidSignatureException();` line.

Comment: Have you checked this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64130722/serializableclosure-error-in-laravel-your-serialized-closure-might-have-been-m

Comment: @AngelMiladinov yes. I'm running these command before I deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue might occur due to change in APP_KEY value in your .env file.

APP_KEY is used for secure data transmission and Laravel recommends to do that by setting it to a random string.

You can run this command:

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
```

Comment: That's the right answer, thanks.