# Why every time I run PHP Artisan Serve it appears like the dashboard that I gor this from where?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

This is my first time use laravel blade and composer, i am so confuse after i run `php artisan serve` When I enter the `http://localhost:8000/news` that should appear the display of the code I wrote in `news.blade.php` but when I run it out as shown in this below
[image]

Anyone can explain me what is this and why this is appear after i run `php artisan serve`.
this is what CMD looks like after running `php artisan serve`.
[image]

Comment: that is error page generated by debugging tool in laravel showing you exception which occurred during handling your request, indicating where and why that error happen so you can fix it, if there wasn't any error you would see your `news.blade.php` as you expect.

Comment: Ohh, Then I'll fix my code, thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem similar to yours I believe it's the same problem

you can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64131281/22906144)

It seems there's a problem with your `APP_KEY` in your `.env` file

if you have any backup of your `.env` file with the `APP_KEY` revert to that or if that's not the case you can generate a key with the following command

```
php artisan key:generate
```

hope it solves the problem

Comment: Yes, i alrd solved and the issues is `APP_KEY` in `.env` file.

Comment: And i forget to run `vite build` so because 2 problem `APP_KEY` and 'vite build' my problem appear. Thanks for your help btw i appreciate it.